# Qt and Ubuntu (Не собирается проект)

Tags: ubuntu, qt

Пытаюсь запустить тестовый (Hello world) на Qt 5.8 (Ubuntu 16.04)
Вот что выбивает:

> :-1: ошибка: cannot find -lGL
>
> :-1: ошибка: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Консоль сборки:

```
13:25:48: Выполняются этапы для проекта HelloWolrd...
13:25:48: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» clean
rm -f moc_predefs.h
rm -f moc_mainwindow.cpp
rm -f ui_mainwindow.h
rm -f main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
13:25:48: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился успешно.
13:25:48: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
13:25:48: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/bin/uic ../HelloWolrd/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../HelloWolrd -I. -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../HelloWolrd/main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../HelloWolrd -I. -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o ../HelloWolrd/mainwindow.cpp
g++ -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -dM -E -o moc_predefs.h ../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/data/dummy.cpp
/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/bin/moc -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include ./moc_predefs.h -I/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/andrey/Working/Qt_work/TESTS/HelloWolrd -I/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -I/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5 -I/usr/include/c++/5/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../HelloWolrd/mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../HelloWolrd -I. -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I../../../../Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib -o HelloWolrd main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/home/andrey/Programs/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
Makefile:232: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «HelloWolrd»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloWolrd] Ошибка 1
13:25:52: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта HelloWolrd (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 GCC 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
13:25:52: Прошло времени: 00:04.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> :-1: ошибка: cannot find -lGL

Означает отсутствие библиотеки OpenGL.

Поставьте пакет `libgl1-mesa-dev`.